# Design consideration around ResultSet and constant declaration of index based retrieval

Tags: java, sql

At the moment I have ten different queries that are handled via JDBC and are wrapped inside functions that return a ResultSet.  Each of these ResultSet objects are iterated over by an external program and will be accessed via their index instead of the column name per requirement.  I have three approaches that I am considering and am looking for the current best practice on how to handle this while remaining as close to pure OO design as possible.  Now my schema looks like this:

```
create table Cats
(  
    name varchar2,
    age number,
    length number,  
    location varchar2,
    isStray varchar2
);
```

Two of my queries are like so:

```
 public ResultSet getAllCats()  
{  
    Select * from Cats;  
}  

public ResultSet getCatAgeAndName(){
    Select cat.age,cat.name from Cats cat
}
```

Now the approaches I have considered to access these properties via `ResultSet.getXXX(index);`

are as follows:

```
public static final int GET_CAT_AGE_AND_NAME_AGE_INDEX = 1;   
public static final int GET_CAT_AGE_AND_NAME_NAME_INDEX = 2;
```

OR

```
public enum GetCatAgeAndNamePosition  
   {  
      AGE(1),
      NAME(2);
   }
```

OR

```
 public class GetCatAgeAndNameQuery  
 {  
      public enum Position  
      {  
           AGE(1),
            NAME(2);
      }  

      private ResultSet results;
 }
```

The first approach is one static final per index per query.
The second is an enum per query.
The third is a class per query.

Which of the above or any other insight to keep this pure and maintainable is available.

Answer (score 0):

I like using `enum`s. They add flexibility. For example, the ordinal value and the name of the column can both be provided. Retrieving by name rather than by ordinal should make things more robust. Would also be safer for queries like `SELECT *`. With an `enum`, it is easier to associate more information, such as `type` information. It is nice to generate these classes based on table meta data.

I tend to go with the `enum` as a private member of a service class which operates on a table, view, or stored proc. It is only used internally to do the mapping from the relational structure to the resultant bean. The relational structure does not need to be exposed externally, so neither does the `enum`. It is also nice to reuse the same `enum` for multiple related queries on the same underlying structure. In your example, the `enum` should have all columns of the table and different queries will use all or some of the columns. Another reason why going by name is nicer than going by index.